# Parsing SQL syntax ANTLR4 via Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, parsing, antlr4

i try to write a parser for Oracle **SQL** with **ANTLR4** in **Python** and can't find working **grammar for SQL parse**. i already try https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/plsql and a lot of same parsers and nothing... all of this doesn't work correctly. Maybe whom know where are i can find some useful information? maybe whom know which **grammar** i need to use for **Python**  to **parse SQL** via **ANTLR4**? Please suggest!

Comment: for oracle i guess.

Comment: Ok, and what is wrong with the grammar you posted?

Comment: and what about [this one][1]?


  [1]: https://github.com/developeron29/PLSQLParser ?

Comment: it doesn't work for me , to many errors , i can show you if you can look please via teamviewer if you understand how to implement it. i already done the parser , whom parse SELECT andrej FROM kazlovskij WHERE legs=4 AND (eyes='green' OR skin='white') and this works well , but only for this string , it's very bad , because if you use another string , it's crash..

Comment: @RadimBača it is java,  i need it for python.

Comment: Not true, you may use grammar (g4 files) and use it any language supporting ANTLR4 to generate the files you need.

Comment: could you spare a couple of minutes please and show me a favor? I'm trying to find and create it for 2 days already, I have everything set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154214/discussion-between-radim-baca-and-andrej).

Comment: @RadimBača Send me the book about ANTLR4 by mail please:)